# Remove subarray from array when one of it's value match another arrays value (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays:

```
$to_import = Array(
  [0] => Array(['native_id'] => 35339920, ['type'] => product)
  [1] => Array(['native_id'] => 22045872, ['type'] => product)
  [2] => Array(['native_id'] => 25913185, ['type'] => profile)
  [3] => Array(['native_id'] => 14354407, ['type'] => profile)
)

$existing = Array(
  [0] => Array(['native_id'] => 22045872)
  [1] => Array(['native_id'] => 25913185)
  [2] => Array(['native_id'] => 30836971)
)
```

I need to remove the record from the first array when the id is found in the second array, and when type matches 'profile'. So in this example, three remain:

```
$to_import = Array(
  [0] => Array(['native_id'] => 35339920, ['type'] => product)
  [1] => Array(['native_id'] => 22045872, ['type'] => product)
  [3] => Array(['native_id'] => 14354407, ['type'] => profile)
)
```

I have found similar questions, but I can't work out how to apply them to my requirements. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24900262/2868238) answer looks like it is close to what I want, but I can't get it to work, my knowledge is failing me.

Comment: You can't have duplicate keys!

Comment: @Rizier123 Updated, can you check and take away the negative if I changed it correctly?

Comment: Why should `22045872` remain?

Comment: @rizier123 Type of 22045872 is product. I only want to remove when it matches native_id and the type is also 'profile'.

Comment: maybe you want to add this to your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$existing_ids = array_column($existing, 'native_id', 'native_id');
$to_import = array_filter($to_import, function ($item) use ($existing_ids) {
    return $item['type'] != 'profile' || !isset($existing_ids[$item['native_id']]);
});
```

We're creating an array `$existing_ids` here which contains all existing ids as its key, so it's extremely quick to look up using `isset`. You could use `in_array` instead, but it'll be slower. From there it's a pretty simple `array_filter` operation.

See http://php.net/array_column. See the comments if you have PHP < 5.5.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

Here I just go through your `$to_import` array with `array_map()` and check if the key is not in the `$keys` array or it is not the type `profile`.

```
<?php

    $keys = array_column($existing, "native_id");
    $result = array_filter(array_map(function($v)use($keys){
        if(!in_array($v["native_id"], $keys) || $v["type"] != "profile")
            return $v;
    }, $to_import));
    print_r($result);

?>
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [native_id] => 35339920
            [type] => product
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [native_id] => 22045872
            [type] => product
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [native_id] => 14354407
            [type] => profile
        )

)
```